# Xcode 5.0 Build Archive gives error file not found libCordova.a

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am creating a phonegap project in Xcode 5.0 , It is working fine with Build and Run in Simulator,
But when i creating archive it gives Linking error -file not found  libCordova.a

I have tried these thing

1. Go to the Build Settings, then Linking, then find Other Linker Flags. Then change $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libCordova.a -----> $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a
2. Under Build Settings in Architectures, change Build Active Architecture Only to YES.

But it still gives same error.

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you `link with libraries` in `build phases`.

[image]